# What is sunproxyadmin service?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server, mcafee

I was trying to run a front end project locally after pulling it down from git. After which I got the following error:

```
vents.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8081
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1501:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! apex-library@1.0.24 dev: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the apex-library@1.0.24 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I was like, "Hold up, i'm not running anything!!". or was I? After running

```
sudo lsof -i :8081
```

I saw:

```
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
cma     265 root   16u  IPv6 0x2756c3c2bce3e369      0t0  TCP *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)
```

I saw that webpack-dev-server was trying to start on the same port as sunproxyadmin

```
...
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    hot: true,
  },
 ...
```

Ok, so what is `sunproxyadmin` and who is `cma` (get off my lawn!!!)
(btw I know how to kill it)

PS: Some one with more stack overflow points who agrees please create tags for sunproxyadmin, EADDRINUSE and cma

Answer (score 20):

After digging around I see that cma is an agent of Mcaffe which is using sunproxyadmin.

I figured I could just find out how to change the port it uses but then I don't have access to change the port that it uses on my machine because it is set by our IT department and the process itself is started by the root user:

> The wakeup port is a global setting, so you can't just change it on
> certain agents: it has to be all of them...
>
> To change the port, simply change it in the Configuration / Server
> Settings page, and the agents will pick up the new port the next time
> they contact the server.

https://community.mcafee.com/t5/ePolicy-Orchestrator/Linux-CMA-Agent-port-chnage/td-p/314596

Most searches on this topic lead to issues with react for some reason which is probably why I found the solution for killing it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10623):

```sh
sudo lsof -n -i4TCP:8081 # get the process' PID
sudo launchctl list | grep 5693 # find the launchd endpoint
sudo launchctl remove com.mcafee.agent.macmn
```

So in the end killing it was my only recourse other than changing the port webpack dev server starts up with.