# express.js server starts on a port that is being used

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, tcp

Have this setup:

- expressjs server started from one node process, listening to port `8081`.
- js client trying to make a request to it from another node process, using node's `http` module.
- client failing with 400 error.
- same URL (http://localhost:8081/) is opening in browser just fine.

Spent a few hours trying to troubleshoot it, then tried to change the port and it worked.
Turns out there is another process listening on port 8081:

```
$ lsof -i tcp:8081                                        
COMMAND    PID            USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
EUSAManag 1187 oleksandr.suhak    4u  IPv4 0xce3bb9546cff3ab1      0t0  TCP localhost:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)
```

(Have no idea what `EUSAManag` is)

I guess my question is: how could it be that the express server starts fine without complaining to a "port being used by another process" when the port is clearly in use. And why does it work then when accessing it from the browser, but does *not* work when making request from js client? Any tips on figuring out what is actually happening here?

Comment: Regarding the used port/service, this might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49877762/3761628, still very weird that your express app is able to start though..

Answer (score 1):

If guess that EUSAManager.exe come from one of software https://iit.com.ua/downloads which is in the business of information security. Most likely their software interfere too much with you operation system.